# SwiftUI Toolbar use in mixed Appkit/SwiftUI app

Tags: macos, swiftui, appkit, nstoolbar

I have a Mac app with an Appkit lifecycle. I would like to create a window that is entirely defined by SwiftUI, including the toolbar.

What I've tried:

1. Programmatically create an `NSWindow` and set its view to be an `NSHostingView` to a SwiftUI view that uses `.toolbar(...)`. **The toolbar does not show up.**
2. Programmatically create an `NSWindow` and an `NSToolbar`, set up the toolbar using Appkit APIs and assign the toolbar to the window. **The toolbar shows up as expected, but is not configured using SwiftUI and it is awkward to have the toolbar reference or interact with SwiftUI view state.**
3. Rewrite the entire app with a SwiftUI lifecycle. **Works fine. Not really an option for me.**

Primary question:

*Is there a way to wire up the toolbar for a manually created `NSWindow` in such a way that SwiftUI views can use the `.toolbar` attributes to place/manage items in it?*

If the answer is simply, "no":

- Is there a way to create a full SwiftUI lifecycle window without the entire app being constructed that way? (I have many non-SwiftUI windows that can't/won't be converted)
- Alternatively, is there a way for the Appkit toolbar code to less awkwardly reference View state in SwiftUI views and/or respond to published changes in SwiftUI state?

Comment: Same here: I can't make `.toolbar` work with `NSHostingView`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60468060/16157878) is an approach that uses `NSWindow.addTitlebarAccessoryViewController` to get a toolbar, which would allow to keep all non-SwiftUI windows.

Comment: There is also [https://github.com/billibala/SUIToolbarPlay], which creates an AppKit `NSToolbar` programmatically, which was probably something like your second attempt.